# How can I access a parameter in a constructor new window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to pass a variable as a parameter from my main window to a new one.

Actually, I can access parameter in an event handler of the new window, but not in the constructor.

mainwindow.xaml.cs :

```
                string selectedKey = “test”;
                EditTri editTri = new EditTri();
                editTri.key = selectedKey;
                editTri.ShowDialog();
```

EditTri.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class EditTri : Window
    {

        public string key;


        public EditTri()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         MessageBox.Show(key);  //key = null ...

        }

        private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(key);   //key = test

            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

I just need to access the parameter `key` in constructor `EditTri()`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a parameter to your constructor:

```
public partial class EditTri : Window
{

    private string _key;

    public EditTri(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
        InitializeComponent();
  
        MessageBox.Show(key); 
    }

    ...
```

**Usage**

```
string selectedKey = “test”;
EditTri editTri = new EditTri(selectedKey);
editTri.ShowDialog();
```

**Warning**, showing a `MessageBox` in a *constructor* is not ideal.

Best do it somewhere like on Loaded event, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! I use messageBox for test only in this code